# Flutter Blue Plus get on button press data from weight scale and convert it to double

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, data-conversion

I need to get an accurate weight value via BLE using the Flutter Blue Plus package in grams when a button is pressed, which calls the getWeight function. The getWeight function takes the data sent from the weight and then returns the value in grams as a double.  Unfortunately, I can't assign the data sent from the scale to a list and convert the corresponding bits to grams. I would like to ask for help.

Results from package inbuilt print:

Weight 335.0 grams

flutter: [FBP] [[ OnCharacteristicReceived ]] result: {remote_id: D5522E08-AAA5-292F-1ADF-6207EF692C2A, secondary_service_uuid: null, characteristic_uuid: fff1, success: 1, value: 1012004101020501f80d167e1f0258020181, error_code: 0, service_uuid: fff0, error_string: success}

Weight 0.0 grams

lfutter: [FBP] [[ OnCharacteristicReceived ]] result: {remote_id: D5522E08-AAA5-292F-1ADF-6207EF692C2A, secondary_service_uuid: null, characteristic_uuid: fff1, success: 1, value: 1012004101020501f900007e1f025802015f, error_code: 0, service_uuid: fff0, error_string: success}

I tried to turn on the subscriptions of characteristics and then the sent value assigned to the int list, unfortunately it did not work.

Code below.

```
// ignore_for_file: unused_import

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart';

class ReadData extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReadData({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ReadData> createState() => _ReadDataState();
}

class _ReadDataState extends State<ReadData> {
  String weightRemoteID = 'D5522E08-AAA5-292F-1ADF-6207EF692C2A';
  String weightServiceID = 'FFF0';
  String weightCharacterisicsID = 'FFF1';
  List<int> weightReceivedValue = [];
  double weightValue = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _wait();
    _startScanning();
    _listenScanResult();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _wait() async {
    await FlutterBluePlus.adapterState
        .where((state) => state == BluetoothAdapterState.on)
        .first;
  }

  void _startScanning() {
    FlutterBluePlus.startScan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 2));
  }

  void _listenScanResult() {
    FlutterBluePlus.setLogLevel(LogLevel.verbose, color: false);
    FlutterBluePlus.scanResults.listen((scanList) async {
      for (ScanResult result in scanList) {
        if (result.device.remoteId.toString() == weightRemoteID) {
          result.device.connect(autoConnect: true);
          List<BluetoothService> services =
              await result.device.discoverServices();
          services.forEach((service) async {
            var characteristics = service.characteristics;
            for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
              await c.setNotifyValue(true);
              weightReceivedValue = await c.read();
              setState(() {
              });
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  double getWeight(List<int> weightReceivedValue) {
    // to code

    return weightValue;
  }

  Widget buildButton(BuildContext context) {
    // to code

    return const FloatingActionButton(onPressed: null);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text("Weight"),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            Text("$getWeight g"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're subscribing to each caracteristic in the devices you're currently connected and after that you are reading each caracteristic (??)

```
await c.setNotifyValue(true);
```

This line is useless if you don't add a listener to the characteristic.

Then, if you wanna add the value to the list weightReceivedValue as a double you need to do this:

```
List<double> weightReceivedValue = [];

var fun = await c.read();

weightReceivedValue.add(double.parse(fun));
```